# how to set value style in center (at TextField Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

how I can handle value in TextField in flutter?

in this picture, you can see this value is up in `Textfield` and I want to this value be center in box:

[image]

I want this hintText value be center I don't know how I can do that.

and I have another problem that is how I can remove underline on this box but it isn't necessary, my first question is important.

this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:project/data/data_nardeban.dart';

class ResultLadder extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {


class _ResultLadderState extends State<ResultLadder> {

  Widget getBody() {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
          color: Colors.white),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  "درصد تخفیف برای 30 عدد",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    decoration:
                        BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Column(
                children: List.generate(nardeban_data.length, (index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: (size.width - 40) * 0.68,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text("14", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white))
              )
            ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      nardeban_data[index]['name'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      nardeban_data[index]['takhfif'],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      ),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: (size.width - 40) * 0.32,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green)),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 10, bottom: 4, left: 10, top: 4),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 25,
                                        width: 25,
                                        child: TextField(
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            hintText: '4%',
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.notifications,
                                size: 16,
                                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Divider()
                ],
              );
            })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SizedBox(
                width: 25,
                height: 25,
                child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: '4%',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top:2, ),

                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove height from sizeBox and make **textAlign: TextAlign.center** in TextField. 
to remove underline from Textfield    **border: InputBorder.none**,
Container(

```
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.green)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: 10, bottom: 4, left: 10, top: 4),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 25,
                    child: TextField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: '4%',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.notifications,
            size: 16,
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: thanks, but the box is big - ه want the height to be smaller | [link](https://ibb.co/dpd2V6w)

Comment: in your above scenario you can use      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top:2, ),